# Deciding whether set of running times is infinite

Tags: turing-machines, computability

I have a language $\mathrm{Count}(M)$, defined below, and a finite number $k$.

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Count}(M)= \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{there exists some input on which $M$ halts after exactly $k$ steps}\}.
\end{align}

I need to check whether the language $L$ is in RE, and whether it is in R.
$$L= \{ \langle M \rangle \mid \text{$\mathrm{Count}(M)$ is an infinite set}\}.$$

My idea for a solution starts with:
even though $L$ is an infinite language, it contains $\mathrm{Count}(M_i)$ that halts eventually. Each $M$ in $L$ must halt, and $\mathrm{Count}(M)$ is infinite.

So, in order to prove that $L$ is in RE, can I simply say every $M$ in $L$ halts eventually?

Comment: If a language is in R, then in particular it is in RE.

Comment: Your solution idea makes me doubt you understand what it means for $L$ to be decidable. It means that given a description of a Turing machine, there is an algorithm that always halts and determines whether Count of the input machine is infinite or not.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "when $M$ halts on $w$ it halts after $k$ steps" -- either $M$ halts on $w$, or it doesn't.  Do you mean "$M$ halts on $w$ after $k$ steps"?  Or something else?

Comment: @D.W. Let $t(M,w)$ be the running time of $M$ on $w$ (possibly $t(M,w) = \infty$). Then $\mathrm{Count}(M) = \{t(M,w) : w \in \Sigma^*, t(M,w) < \infty\}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, ok, cool, that makes sense.  Can I encourage you to edit the question accordingly?

Comment: I was also confused by the wording, particularly by "after $k$ steps". Originally I had interpreted it to mean: $k$ is in $\textrm{Count}(M)$  if there is some input $w$ such that $M$ halts on $w$ and $t(M,w) > k$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $L \in \textrm{RE}$.
Given a Turing machine $M$ you can construct another Turing machine $M'$ that takes an input $x$ and simulates $M$ on an empty input for at most $|x|$ steps.

If $M$ eventually halts, say after $c$ steps, $M'$ will always halt after at most $f(c)$ steps, (for some function $f$), regardless of the choice of $x$. This shows that $\textrm{Count}(M') \subseteq \{ 1, \dots, f(c) \}$ is a finite set.

If $M$ does not halt, then $M'$ will halt after simulating $|x|$ steps of $M$ for every choice of $x$. By picking different values of $x$ it is possible to build an infinite set of inputs such that each input results in a different running time of $M'$ (e.g, start with $x=$"1" and let $s$ be the number of steps taken by $M'$ on input $x$. The next value of $x$ will be a string of $s+1$ ones, so that $M'$ necessarily halts after some number $\ell$ of steps such that $\ell \ge s+1$. The next value of $x$ will have $\ell+1$ ones, and so on).

This shows that $\textrm{Count}(M')$ is an infinite set.

Therefore, since $L \in \textrm{RE}$ you have just found a way to accept all (and only) the Turing machines $M$ that do not halt on an empty input, showing that the complement of the halting problem is in $\textrm{RE}$. 
This is a contradiction as it would imply that the halting problem is in $\textrm{R}$.

Comment: i really appreciate it! can you explain me what ℓ stands for?

Comment: It's just a name for the number of steps that $M'$ will perform before halting when its input is a string of $s+1$ ones.